# Watching the upcoming movie "Napoleon"

Tags: halacha, performance-entertainment

With the blockbuster period drama "Napoleon" coming out next month, my question is is it permissible to watch a film about a rasha who happened to be a major historical figure, whether for entertainment or educational purposes?

Comment: Why would you think that Napoleon was a bad person?

Comment: @TheGRAPKE They say the Alter Rebbe believed he was a sorcerer: https://heichalhanegina.blogspot.com/2007/01/rav-baal-hatanya-and-napoleons-march.html

Comment: ... while R' Levi Yitzchak of Berdichev prayed for Napoleon's victory. It's complicated.

Comment: Surely the first question would be whether the film is kosher to watch regardless of the character? Tznius, nivul peh etc.

Comment: He was a tyrannical, power-hungry conqueror who embodied the trait of gaivah. Also his stipulation for leaving the Jews alone was that they should completely assimilate into French society. I'm not sure why I deserve to be downvoted just for asking this question?

Comment: @RabbiKaii the way I've generally heard it is that the Alter Rebbe prayed that the Czar win, as Napoleonic victory meant the Jews would assimilate. The Berdichever prayed that Napoleon win, as the Jews would suffer less.

Comment: @Shalom yes, thanks for jogging my memory you are right

Comment: @shmosel Anyone who channels *kochos ha'tumah* could be defined as a sorcerer but that probably includes every single president of the USA and any rock star, who you could not rightly define as *reshaim*.

Comment: I find every part of that statement questionable. And according to the story I linked, Napoleon was specifically looking for the Alter Rebbe's belongings in order to harm him.